# How to convert selected rows into a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have been working with a dataset which requires me to split certain selected rows and convert them into columns. The spread function which I normally use for these kind of things didn't exactly work the way I wanted. This is closest reproducible example that I have got:

```
df<-data.frame(person=c("Matt","Tom","Shane","Shane"),salary=c(100,200,500,400))
> df
  person salary
1   Matt    100
2    Tom    200
3  Shane    500
4  Shane    400
```

Suppose this is the Data Frame that I have got, how do I split the rows where person == Shane into a seperate column? This is what I have been trying to achieve:

```
  person salary  Shane
1   Matt    100  500
2   Tom     200  400
```

How do I go about doing this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure why you would want to do this, but using dplyr:

```
df2<-filter(df,person!='Shane')
df2$Shane<-filter(df,person=='Shane')$salary
> df2
  person salary Shane
1   Matt    100   500
2    Tom    200   400
```

Comment: Hi @august I'm looking for something similar and this is the best answer I have found. Thanks. How would execute some thing similar if you had unequal lengths e.g. you have 17 rows but one 5 values to fill column 'Shane' above?